# Force kill a running thread

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am building an application in which in an activity, I am using 2 threads,

```
1-main thread,
2-other thread
```

Now in some circumstances I want to force kill another thread,so that only my main thread should work..

currently I am using it as:

```
if(other_thread!=null)
   other_thread.interrupt();
```

but in `interrupt()` method,when main thread completed its task,then other thread started doing its task..And my requirement is my application ends when main thread completed its task..So instead of using `interrupt()`,which steps I should follow to force kill this other_thread??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't recommend you using the `interrupt()` method or any other techniques of thread killing. If you have a thread with a `while` loop inside, you can control this thread by a boolean `flag` for the `while` condition. When you set the flag to `false` the thread just finishes its task. Then you can call `thread.join()` from your main thread to be sure that the other thread has finished execution. Hope this helps.

Here's a little example:

```
boolean flag = true;
Thread secondary = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (flag) {
        // do something
        }
    }
});
secondary.start(); //start the thread
flag = false; // this will force secondary to finish its execution
try {
    secondary.join(); // wait for secondary to finish
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: I am not getting it properly.can u please explain me more?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a variable which makes the thread run while that condition is true or something similiar. You could make a method inside that thread, and set the variable to false or similiar in order to break the loop which makes the thread run.